# Exclude rows based on values on other rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following values in a table called CART:

```
ID  EMP_EMAIL       PRODUCT ACTIVITY_TYPE
1   USER@EMAIL.COM  Book    Add
2   USER@EMAIL.COM  Book    Remove
3   USER@EMAIL.COM  Kindle  Add
4   USER@EMAIL.COM  Kindle  Remove
5   USER@EMAIL.COM  Phone   Add
6   USER@EMAIL.COM  Phone   Remove
7   USER@EMAIL.COM  Book    Add
```

At the end I need to remain with just one line, the last one Add Book.

The rows are ordered in sequential order. This means that the user selected a book. Then removed the book and selected a Kindle. Then removed the Kindle and selected a phone and so on.

At the end I just need to output that the user selected a Book.

This example could also have a null output:

```
ID  EMP_EMAIL       PRODUCT ACTIVITY_TYPE
1   USER@EMAIL.COM  Book    Add
2   USER@EMAIL.COM  Book    Remove
3   USER@EMAIL.COM  Kindle  Add
4   USER@EMAIL.COM  Kindle  Remove
5   USER@EMAIL.COM  Phone   Add
6   USER@EMAIL.COM  Phone   Remove
```

This shouldn't return anything as the last action was a remove.

I'm open to any suggestions either in sql or pl/sql.

Comment: Are the ads and removes always alternating?

Comment: What did you try ? Or is it like you want someone from SO to do it for you

Comment: Will the data contain multiple values for emp_email? If so, will the values be numbered consecutively for each value? How is this different from "retrieving the last row if the activity_type is add"? Do you guarantee that for a given emp_email, the consecutive activity types will never e the same? Not nearly enough information in your problem statement - and SO exists to help you fix a problem not to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select everything that was added, but not removed.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
select c.*
from cart c
where c.activity_type = 'Add' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from cart c2
                  where c2.emp_email = c.emp_email and
                        c2.product = c.product and
                        c2.activity_type = 'Remove'
                 );
```

If you want to select items that have more adds then removes:

```
select c.emp_email, c.product
from cart
group by c.emp_email, c.product
having sum(case when c.activity_type = 'Add' then 1
                when c.activity_type = 'Remove' then -1
           end) > 0;
```

Comment: @jpw . . . Good catch.  Obviously, the OP needs to deal with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

it will list the prodct which were added but no removed.

```
SELECT emp_email,product
    FROM test
    GROUP BY (emp_email,product) 
    HAVING CASE WHEN SUM(CASE activity_type WHEN 'Add' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)!=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1;
```